# T shaped tetris figures on a plane

Tags: general-topology, geometry, set-theory, problem-solving, packing-problem

I am just wondering how many (and by how many I mean countably or uncountably many) T shaped figures can we place on a XY plane. I assume that that T consists of 2 perpendicular lines and has 0 area.

It is easy to understand for L shaped figures or U shaped ones, one can place uncountably many of those. But I am unable to construct a similar bijection for T shaped ones. I believe that it should be countable and some sort of diagonal argument should be made but I don't know how.

A reasonable followup is for the X shaped ones. How many of those can we fit on a plane?

Comment: You mean two perpendicular line segments? Or two perpendicular lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out it is impossible to have uncountably many disjoint `T`s in the plane. I found this solution in *Mathematical Puzzles: A Connoisseur's Collection* by Peter Winkler.

> Let $S$ be the set of ordered triples of disjoint disks in the plane whose centers have rational coordinates and whose radii are rational. Note $S$ is countable.
>
> Given any arrangement of disjoint `T`s in the plane, define a map from these `T`s to $S$ by choosing, for each `T`, a triple in $S$ whose disks each contain one of the three endpoints of the `T`, so that each disk only touches one of the three line segments comprising the `T`.
>
> I claim this map is at most two-to-one. If not, then there would be a triple $(D_1,D_2,D_3)$ which was joined together by three non-overlapping `T`s. But this would be a solution to the [water gas electricity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem) in the plane, which is impossible. Specifically, the disks are the utilities, and the intersection points of the `T`s are the houses.
>
> Since there is an at most two-to-one map from the set of `T`s to a countable set, the set of `T`s must be countable.

Notes:

- Perhaps there is a simpler solution; the one I just gave generalizes to prove that you cannot fit uncountably many disjoint sets in the plane which are *homeomorphic* to the shape `T`.
- The axiom of choice is not required to construct this map; $S$ can be well-ordered, so give each `T` the smallest legal triple in the well-ordering.

Comment: Note: This "T" problem is usually presented short after the "8" problem, which is used as a warm-up (you pick pairs of rational points, one in each eye)